# Python Import csv file as dataframe with File chooser

Tags: csv, python-2.7, dataframe, filechooser

I would like to import a csv file into python with FileChooser and display it as dataframe. Here is the code and it didn't work. Thanks for your kind help.

```
def get_open_filename(self):

    filename = None
    chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open File...", self.window,
                                    gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                    (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, 
                                     gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

    response = chooser.run()
    if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK: 
        with open(chooser.get_filename(), 'rb') as csvfile:
            don = DataFrame.from_csvfile(csvfile)           ## I am confused here !!!
            print don
    chooser.destroy()

    return filename
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" is "don" empty? Do you get an error?

Comment: The dialog box is launched. When I Click on the csv file, nothing is done and once closed the gui, I have this: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <type 'file'> at the moment.

Comment: Are you using rpy2? (It's not clear what a DataFrame is from the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe from_csv file takes a filename not a file, using these [docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/robjects.html?highlight=from_csv#rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame.from_csvfile)
Try replacing

```
with open(chooser.get_filename(), 'rb') as csvfile:
    don = DataFrame.from_csvfile(csvfile)           ## I am confused here !!!
    print don
```

with

```
    don = DataFrame.from_csvfile(chooser.get_filename())
    print don
```

Comment: Yes it works doctorlove with your code. Yes I have used rpy2! Many Thanks. But I got this while the dataframe don i displayed: Unable to unlink tempfile c:\users\~\appdata\local\temp\tmpzq4zao